# Ubuntu 23.04: No Speaker Sound with Realtek ALC245 on HP ENVY Laptop

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, alsa, hp

No sound from internal speaker

I have tried ubuntu 22.04, 22.10, 23.04 still no sound

```
$ uname -a
Linux HP-ENVY 6.2.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  6 07:48:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME
    v: 44.0 Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
Machine:
  Type: Convertible System: HP product: HP ENVY x360 2-in-1 Laptop 13-bf0xxx
    v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8A28 v: 21.39 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Insyde
    v: F.07 date: 12/23/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 29.8 Wh (48.7%) condition: 61.2/66.5 Wh (92.1%)
    volts: 7.6 min: 7.7 model: Hewlett-Packard PABAS0241231 status: discharging
CPU:
  Info: 10-core (2-mt/8-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i7-1250U bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP arch: Alder Lake rev: 4 cache: L1: 928 KiB L2: 6.5 MiB
    L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1610 high: 1900 min/max: 400/4700:3500 cores: 1: 1900
    2: 1900 3: 677 4: 1900 5: 1900 6: 1900 7: 626 8: 1900 9: 1900 10: 927
    11: 1900 12: 1900 bogomips: 45158
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-UP4 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-12.2
    bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 2880x1800~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.2 renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2)
    direct-render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: N/A bus-ID: 00:05.0
  Device-2: Intel vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.0-20-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:14.3
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 2-10:2
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 19.7 GiB (4.1%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Micron model: MTFDKBA512TFH-1BC1AABHA
    size: 476.94 GiB temp: 36.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 152.73 GiB used: 19.61 GiB (12.8%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 256 MiB used: 92.9 MiB (36.3%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 35.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 fan-2: 0
Info:
  Processes: 346 Uptime: 12m Memory: 15.3 GiB used: 3.95 GiB (25.8%)
  Init: systemd target: graphical (5) Compilers: gcc: 12.2.0 Packages: 1934
  Shell: Bash v: 5.2.15 inxi: 3.3.25
```

```
$ journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sournd|hda.codec|hda.intel"
Apr 28 22:23:23 HP-ENVY kernel: cs35l41-hda i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: Error: ACPI _DSD Properties are missing for HID CSC3551.
Apr 28 22:23:23 HP-ENVY kernel: cs35l41-hda i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: error -EINVAL: Platform not supported
Apr 28 22:23:23 HP-ENVY kernel: cs35l41-hda: probe of i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0 failed with error -22
Apr 28 22:23:23 HP-ENVY kernel: cs35l41-hda i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: Error: ACPI _DSD Properties are missing for HID CSC3551.
Apr 28 22:23:23 HP-ENVY kernel: cs35l41-hda i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: error -EINVAL: Platform not supported
Apr 28 22:23:23 HP-ENVY kernel: cs35l41-hda: probe of i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1 failed with error -22
Apr 28 22:23:24 HP-ENVY kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
Apr 28 22:23:24 HP-ENVY kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
Apr 28 22:23:24 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
Apr 28 22:23:24 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
Apr 28 22:23:24 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Apr 28 22:23:24 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
Apr 28 22:23:25 HP-ENVY kernel: Modules linked in: bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi iwlmvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_i2c snd_hwdep snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41 coretemp mac80211 snd_pcm snd_hda_cs_dsp_ctls cs_dsp snd_soc_cs35l41_lib kvm_intel snd_seq_midi joydev i915(+) libarc4 snd_seq_midi_event kvm irqbypass snd_rawmidi drm_buddy crct10dif_pclmul ttm polyval_clmulni polyval_generic drm_display_helper btusb snd_seq ghash_clmulni_intel btrtl sha512_ssse3 cec btbcm hid_sensor_rotation hid_sensor_accel_3d aesni_intel hid_sensor_als hid_sensor_gyro_3d
Apr 28 22:23:25 HP-ENVY kernel:  snd_seq_device hid_sensor_custom_intel_hinge rc_core btintel hid_sensor_trigger iwlwifi pmt_telemetry crypto_simd snd_timer industrialio_triggered_buffer btmtk processor_thermal_device_pci cryptd kfifo_buf mei_hdcp mei_pxp intel_rapl_msr pmt_class drm_kms_helper cmdlinepart processor_thermal_device rapl hid_sensor_iio_common bluetooth hp_wmi(+) snd spi_nor processor_thermal_rfim i2c_algo_bit ecdh_generic mei_me processor_thermal_mbox ecc syscopyarea platform_profile wmi_bmof ucsi_acpi mtd 8250_dw cfg80211 intel_cstate industrialio sysfillrect processor_thermal_rapl soundcore mei typec_ucsi sysimgblt igen6_edac intel_vsec intel_rapl_common typec hi556 v4l2_fwnode serial_multi_instantiate intel_skl_int3472_tps68470 tps68470_regulator v4l2_async clk_tps68470 videodev int3403_thermal input_leds int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal mc acpi_thermal_rel intel_skl_int3472_discrete intel_hid sparse_keymap soc_button_array acpi_tad acpi_pad hid_multitouch serio_raw mac_hid msr
Apr 28 22:23:26 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
Apr 28 22:23:26 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
Apr 28 22:23:26 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
Apr 28 22:23:26 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
Apr 28 22:23:26 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 2
Apr 28 22:23:26 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
Apr 28 22:23:26 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
Apr 28 22:23:26 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: autoconfig for ALC245: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    inputs:
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:      Mic=0x19
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: sink widget AIF1TX overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: source widget AIF1RX overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget hifi3 overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget hifi2 overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget hifi1 overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Codec Output Pin1 overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Codec Input Pin1 overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Analog Codec Playback overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Digital Codec Playback overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Alt Analog Codec Playback overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Analog Codec Capture overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Digital Codec Capture overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Alt Analog Codec Capture overwritten
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: hda_dsp_hdmi_build_controls: no PCM in topology for HDMI converter 3
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input15
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input16
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input17
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input18
Apr 28 22:23:27 HP-ENVY kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input19
```

Along with sound multiple hardware also not working:-

1. No audio on internal speakers, works fine on headphones and Bluetooth
2. Wake from Suspend loops forcing hard power-off in order to recover
3. Webcam not recognised
4. Touchscreen not recognised

I can survive without 2 & 4 but please help me resolve case 1 & 3

++ hp laptops really sucks, never gone buy them again

Comment: me too, I suffered for years with X360's , three of them. I have concluded they do not do AMD microcode very well, and are windows fixated .  latest BIOS update is misnamed and same as the previous one. gone over to ASUS TUF, never looked back.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This laptop is missing Linux specific configuration in the BIOS. When speaker driver probes it cannot find ACPI entry for Cirrus CS35L41 amps. Needs to be sorted by HP BIOS team.

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled a small github repo to fix both the speaker and suspend resume problems. The repo contains workarounds for the missing audio amp ACPI entry and the unexpected internal display connection. Just follow the README. Note that this has only been tested to work on model 13-bf0xxx and on Debian 12 (which should also work for Ubuntu). Use this on other distros at your own risk. Please do not try on other HP laptops as the topology of the speaker amp (CS35L41) may be different.

https://github.com/Jerryxia32/envy_x360_fix

This laptop is absolutely amazing on Linux once you sort out speaker and suspend resume issues. Once these are fixed, this laptop gives you crazy battery life. It idles at 1.7W (lasts 39 hours) even with the display at a usable brightness! It sleeps at around 300mW (lasts almost 10 days) and consumes only 6.8W (almost 10 hours) watching 4K 60fps youtube videos on Firefox. I've never seen such low power consumption on any laptop to be honest (except Arm Macs), and such low power cannot be achieved in Windows on this laptop no matter how hard I try.

Note that touch screen and the webcam are still not supported.