# Ubuntu 23.10 - Wired/Wireless Headphone NOT DETECTED

Tags: 23.10

Tried many methods but nothing works.
Both the headphone jack and the hardware works in any Windows OS but NOT in any Ubuntu Linux OS.

Here's my Hardware Model: HP Laptop 15s-fq4xxx
I'm currently using: Ubuntu 23.10 (Software is Updated)

Comment: did you look for the device in `Settings > Sound > Output` using the drop down to select your headphones?

Comment: There is a long thread (https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/No-sound-from-internal-speakers-using-Linux/td-p/8478057) on HP forums about it and a similar Ask Ubuntu question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465753/ubuntu-23-04-no-speaker-sound-with-realtek-alc245-on-hp-envy-laptop)